# No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key'

Tags: ajax, rest, api, odata

I have one API which works fine for all the methods for below scenario except for update method when published to IIS.
When I use, the local path of API as http://localhost:87/ call is made to API and customer gets updated successfully
And when I changed an API path to http://ipaddress or machine name: 87/ there is an error in fiddler as below
InnerError:
             The message=No routing convention was found to select an action for the O Data path with template '~/entity set/key'.
The message=No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://ipaddress or machine name: 87/evolution/Customers (GUID of customer)'.
below is the Ajax call:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: webServiceUrl + "/evol/Customers(" + customerId + ")",
            type: "PATCH",
            data: customer,
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            dataType: 'json',


            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                alert(result.value);
            },
            error: function (result, request, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding this method in seperate controller at API side.